# Parallel Processing, inside loop, can we access the Degree of Parallelism?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

In the following loop, I want to add logic to say if processor 1 then do this, if processor 2 do that etc. I have been trying various properties like ...

```
Console.WriteLine("Domain ID = " + Thread.GetDomainID().ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Thread ID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
```

...but i see thread ID is counting up and up so its the thread where many threads to a processor. So how to get the 1-4 inside the loop? The DomainID I just get the same value

```
Parallel.ForEach(list.OrderBy(n => n.ScheduledBillingId),
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4  }, (item) => { });
```

My issue is I want this to be able to split the records in the list into 4 groups and process 1 deals with the first 25% and so on.

Comment: I'd usually recommend against using `parallel.foreach` inside asp.net code - asp.net is already trying to use the thread pool to process multiple *requests* simultaneously.

Comment: If you want to do something different in each thread, then `Parallel.ForEach` may not be the right tool. Can you clarify exactly what you need and why? For instance, could you show what kind of code you would write if you had the information you're searching for?

Comment: foreach (ScheduledBilling item in list.OrderBy(n => n.ScheduledBillingId)) 
                {

                }

I just want to have this web job process different batch of this list in parallel to speed it all up. Since end to end its slow

Comment: But my worry is it is trying to run the same item at the same time since i get database errors. As if say process 1 and process 2 etc all try to action the first item. New to parallel processing and not sure if I need to do more

Comment: *Partitioning* isn't related to DOP. Indirectly, `Parallel.For/Foreach` use the DOP for partitioning. Why do you care though? Each task does the same job as any other. You shouldn't care at all which task a record gests processed on

Comment: On the other hand, parallelizing a bad query is only going to make it worse - a lot worse. Parallel operations won't speed up bad queries and definitely *won't* run any faster that a SqlBulkCopy operation. If you have a problem with your database code, post the database code. You *won't* get any improvements if you try to write to the same disk from multiple threads. Batch all new rows together and send them all in a single call

Comment: Is there a way to know the process inside the loop, i.e. 1-4. This is all I need. The query is efficient and not the issue. The inner based call is because it generates a PDF file and there is a great deal of validation. Ongoing this will be getting improved/tuned. But we want to throw hardware at this and need a quick way to get more than 1 train running, by using 4

Comment: I never mentioned before, this is a web job running singular, not part of the website asp.net solution. So the idea is, it takes say 1 hour for the code to do 100 tasks, so i want 4 tasks running to do the job quicker. Problem is how to tell the 4 processes to not step on each others toes since its a database. I get 'An item with the same key has already been added' error

Answer (score 1):

For your job and `Parallel.ForEach` you can use a [partitioner for your list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853.aspx), like this:

```
// Partition the entire source array.
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, list.Count);
```

After that you simply provide that partitioner for your loop:

```
Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) =>
{
    // Loop over each range element without a delegate invocation.
    for (var i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; ++i)
    {
        var taskToRun = list[i];
    }
});
```

As you want to split your tasks by 4 groups, you just need a [proper overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx):

```
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, source.Length, source.Length / 4);
```